# Visual Studio library: Pulling in Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget, release

I am using VS2019 to create a simple class library. It depends on Netwonsoft.Json and the project is setup to pull that in from NuGet. Testing is complete and all works great.

Now, when the end user (the developer) adds my library as a reference in their project, it does not pull in Netwonsoft.Json automatically. I have been looking at articles but most are for "project dependencies" for compilation. So I must be missing something.

What part of VS should I be looking at so that the end developer gets the project dependencies?

Comment: You need to include the `dll` alongside your application.

Comment: Depends on how you are providing it to your end user.  Copy/paste?  NuGet?

Comment: The right way to distribute this is as a nuget package (internally published most likely) that lists the Newtonsoft target as a package referenche.

Comment: Fairly straightforward, I just have the project on the company share. they browse to the bin folder and add my DLL to their project. We don't have NuGet internally.

Comment: your package should add `Newtonsoft.Json` as a package dependency https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element